# Is GWT-RPC and RequestFactory mutually exclusive?

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-rpc, requestfactory

Can I use both in the same project? Or do they cause "network interference" with one another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use simultaneously any Ajax mechanism in GWT, they are not exclusive, so you can select the most suitable one for each necessity in your product.

For instance, I have an application which uses RF for entities and business requests, gwt-atmosphere (which uses RPC) for comet comunications, and gwtquery-Ajax (which uses RequestBuilder) for consuming 3party json services.

Answer (score 1):

It does not cause any kind of interference. In the end you are just sending HTTP request to a servlet. You client can handle (pseudo) simultaneous queries as your server.

So you can use different method to query your server. The point is more about maintenance/re-usability/readability of your code.

I would advise you to use only one way for querying your server.

IMO you should avoid using RPC as much as you can and look into more standard way of communicating with your server (RequestFactory or simply requestBuilder or even REST libraries like restyGWT) so that your server is not linked to your GWT client.

Comment: Many times it is impossible to use just a method. RF or RPC does not support consuming json services, RF does not have any comet implementation. etc

Comment: I think comet is really an advanced topic and that the question was fairly general for simple client/server communication.